# Find the equivalent capacitance of the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, capacitance, homework

[image: circuit with capacitors placed in parallel and series.]

How do I first approach this circuit?
I first added the farthest 2pF series capacitors to get C_eq of 1pF and then added the 3pF and C_eq to achieve 4pF.

Is this how to calculate the equivalent capacitance of the circuit?

I arrived at a total equivalence of 9/7 pF.

Clarification would be appreciated

Comment: Capacitors in series add like resistances in parallel. What's the reciprocal of 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4?